# How to convert a Gdiplus::GpBitmap* to Gdiplus::Bitmap*?

Tags: c++, winapi, autohotkey, gdi+

I'm using `AutoHotkey` the source is written in `c++` and internally it uses the `GDI+ Flat API`.

Im creating `bitmaps` into `script` using the `Gdiplus.dll`, something like:

`DllCall("gdiplus.dll\GdipCreateBitmapFromFile", "WStr", File, "PtrP", Bitmap)`

The `bitmap` is created as `GpBitmap*`.

I'm not able to get everything done using only these functions written in `AutoHotkey`, but I can find the functions done in `c++`.

I have built some of them into the `AutoHotkey` source, but these functions expect a `Gdiplus::Bitmap*`, I understand that I'm not supposed to use both, but as my knowledge in `c++` is limited, I'm not able to write everything using just one of these APIs.

I would like to ask if is possible to convert the `GpBitmap*` to `Gdiplus::Bitmap*` and vice-versa.

Comment: Looking at [this bitmap function reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-bitmap-flat) it seems like `GpBitmap` is more of a C structure, while `Bitmap` is a C++ class wrapping the C API. You should probable use one of the other, but not both.

Comment: The flat vs OO APIs are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat . In general you use one or the other, but not boths. All classes use GpXX structs as protected members and protected ctors. You can derive from Bitmap yourself and create a new `public MyBitmap(GpBitmap* img) : Gdiplus::Bitmap(img)` ctor but it's convoluted. Why do you need to use both APIs in the first place?

Comment: you can refer to @SimonMourier 's solution and [It is recommended that you do not directly call the functions in the flat API. Microsoft Product Support Services will not provide support for code that calls the flat API directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-flatapi-flat).

Comment: What can you do with Bitmap class that you cannot do with flat functions?